# Difference between $q constructor and promise interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- What is a promise interface in angular JS?
- Also what is a $q constructor?
- When are these used and what is the difference between them?

I referred few sources but couldn't get the difference. Any pointers?

Comment: That shows no initiative on your part

Comment: as I said I referred few sources

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also you would get most of the related info on the official documentation

Comment: Now is the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Worth visiting: **[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)**

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`.

Comment: Yes I'll make notes on that thnkuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the definition for promise and $q,

> A promise is a special type of Object that we can either use, or construct ourselves to handle asynchronous tasks. We deem them promises because we are “promised” a result at a future point in time. For example an HTTP call could complete in 200ms or 400ms, a promise will execute when resolved.
>
> A promise has three states, pending, resolved or rejected. Using $q in Angular, we can construct our own promises, however let’s look at the ECMAScript2015 Promise Object first to get familiar on how to create one.

you can get more knowledge from this site: https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q

Comment: For future visitors: `ES2015` is ECMAScript2015.